# vscode can't launch node app

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, launch

I'm trying to set up a typescript-based express app workflow using Visual Studio Code & gulp.

Heres my project structure:

```
src/  <-- souce files
  Start.ts
  Server.ts
  models/
    Contact.ts
    Organization.ts
bin/  <-- compiled output
  Start.js 
  Start.js.map
  ...
tsconfig.json
gulpfile.json
package.json
.vscode/
  launch.json
```

Performing the following sequence of commands, I can compile & launch my app in the integrated terminal:

```
> tsc
> node --debug-brk ./bin/Start.js
```

At this point, I can successfully attach to my app using the default "attach to process" command (and it even hits breakpoints in the typescript files correctly, yeyy!):

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach to Process",
    "address": "localhost",
    "port": 5858
}
```

*However*, **launching with `F5` fails every time**. There is no output on the Debug Console, and in a few seconds I get an error banner at the top saying `Cannot connect to runtime via 'legacy' protocol; consider using 'inspector' protocol (timeout after 10000 ms).`

Here's my launch configuration (in launch.json):

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Program",

    // Using compiled .js file. vscode should use the sourcemap to correlate
    // with breakpoints in the source file
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Start.js",
    "outFiles": [ "${workspaceRoot}/bin/**/*.js" ]
}
```

**I tried opening the debug console**. Every time I save the launch.json file, it gives me the following error: `Cannot read property '_runner' of undefined: TypeError: Cannot read property '_runner' of undefined` in `shell.ts:426`

Googling the error, I came across [this bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22606)

What does this bug mean? Is there any workaround for it? What oh what should I do???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small things always cause the biggest problems.

The issue was that I had the "Attach to Process" task selected (in the debug mode dropdown) rather then the "Launch Program" task. So, when I pressed `F5`, vscode was trying to attach to an already running process rather than launch a new one.

**facepalm**

Answer (score 0):

I cant tell you what the bug means but below I will give an example of the launch config that works for me in the similar environment to yours:

```
    {
        // Name of configuration; appears in the launch configuration drop down menu.
        "name": "Launch Server",
        // Type of configuration.
        "type": "node2",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the program.
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/server/app.ts",
        // Automatically stop program after launch.
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        // Command line arguments passed to the program.
        "args": [],
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the working directory of the program being debugged. Default is the current workspace.
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the runtime executable to be used. Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        // Optional arguments passed to the runtime executable.
        "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy"],
        // Environment variables passed to the program.
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        // Use JavaScript source maps (if they exist).
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "request": "launch",
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceRoot}/dist/dev/*/*.js"
        ]           
    }
```

Note the differences in `type` that is set to `node2` and `program` pointing to ts instead of js.

Hope this can help.

Comment: What's the significance of `node2`?

Comment: There is nothing special about it: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.node-debug2 It used to help me in 'strange' cases, but if you have latest VSCode the node2 is deprecated and automaticaly switched to: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_node2-transitioning